# How can I convert a string or multiple strings into different ranges within a byte array in Java?

Tags: java, string, char, buffer, arrays

I have a set of strings for fields like name, userID, email, etc. which need to go into a byte[] array of a certain size (1024 bytes).

I would love to find a method/function that would allow me to simply use my index variable bufferPosition like the following:

> byteArray[bufferPosition] += name += userID += email;
>
> bufferPosition += name.length() += userID.length() += email.length();

So far, all I've found are ways to convert strings into byte arrays directly, and some seemingly tedious ways of solving this problem (i.e. treating each element of the string as a character, converting to byte, creating a looping construct and inserting each element).

EDIT: Follow up

I also have fields that are String[] arrays, consisting of up to 14 elements. This would be the most tedious part. Would I be able to use a similar for-each loop? I assume there is an extremely clever way to figure this out.

Comment: The tedious way is the right way.

Comment: you should save the offsets (so the positions) of the fields? Or just need the flat array?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question entirely. All I need is for the strings to be entered into the array consecutively. I assume this is flat array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
// some dummy data
byte[] myByteArr = new byte[1024];
String name = "name";
String userId = "userId";
int bufferPosition = 0;

// repeat this for all of your fields...
byte[] stringBytes = name.getBytes();  // get bytes from string
System.arraycopy(stringBytes, 0, myByteArr, bufferPosition, stringBytes.length);  // copy src to dest
bufferPosition += stringBytes.length;  // advance index
```

You could do it using a loop, in such a way (using your field names):

```
String[] myFields = new String[]{name, userID, email};  // put your fields in an array or list

// loop through each field and copy the data
for (String field : myFields) {
    byte[] stringBytes = field.getBytes();  // get bytes from string
    System.arraycopy(stringBytes, 0, myByteArr, bufferPosition, stringBytes.length);  // copy src to dest
    bufferPosition += stringBytes.length;  // advance index
}
```

You will need to ensure you don't exceed the bounds of the array, but this is a simple example.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant! I'll give the second one a shot. Thank you!

Comment: I've also got fields I need to transcribe into this buffer that are String arrays themselves, holding up to 14 elements. Will I ultimately need to rewrite that kind of code for them? 


I was hoping there would be a way to create a multidimensional arrays String[][] myField, and then do a similar for:each loop. I'm guessing that's wishful thinking, though!

Comment: You will need to convert each element to bytes, as the array itself will be an object containing `String` objects, that will need to be converted individually. You could experiment with serialization to do what you want, but you'll likely have to expel a little legwork to get what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a working solution. When you deserialize that byte array, how will you figure out where the first string ends and the second starts?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly improved version (thx @Ryan J):

```
private static byte[] bytesFromStrings(final String... data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final byte[] result = new byte[1024];
    int bufferPosition = 0;
    if (data != null) {
        for (String d : data) {
            final byte[] stringBytes = d.getBytes("UTF-8");
            if (bufferPosition > 1023) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(stringBytes, 0, result, bufferPosition, Integer.min(1024 - bufferPosition, stringBytes.length));
                bufferPosition = Integer.min(bufferPosition + stringBytes.length, 1024);
            }   
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

..with null/overflow handling and dynamic data :-)

EDIT: ...and some portability considerations. (`d.getBytes()`)